# ps utility does not show the year a process was started

Tags: unix, hp-ux, ps

I am doing some work on a fairly old system and need to know when a couple of processes started. When I use "ps -ef" one says October 18 and the other March 23. We haven't got to October 18 this year so I'm not sure if this is October 18 last year or the previous year. The uptime command is showing 2419 days (6.6 years!) so it's possible the Oct 18 is from earlier than 2012. This is a HP-UX system. I have done a bit of googling and none of the answers I came across worked, eg ps -o, looking in the /proc dir.

```
  cfgmgr  9947  9943  3  Mar 23  ?        6831:32 /home/cfgmgr/bin/snmpagt
    root 24338     1  0  Oct 18  ?        2628:13 /usr/sbin/snmpdm -tcplocal
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PS can only show the date because as per PS documentation at MAN page

'Only the year will be displayed if the process was not started the same year ps was invoked, or "mmmdd" if it was not started the same day, or "HH:MM" otherwise.'

Comment: For your easy reference 
http://linuxcommando.blogspot.in/2008/09/how-to-get-process-start-date-and-time.html    
http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ps